# Can one print on the same line after user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, user-input

I am relatively new to python and have to write a code for a "Countdown" based game; the program would basically ask the user for a word, see whether it is located in a file of words, and if it **isn't** print (*directly after* the word input by the user) "is invalid".

[Here is the portion of code relative to this (I would supply the whole thing but I'm actually in France so it's in French...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmrfD.png)

[And here is what I see on my screen now, relative to what I have been asked for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXtjA.png)

I'm also new to this forum so apologies in advance if this post isn't as polished as others!

Many thanks in advance to anyone willing to help, it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it essential to have it on the same line?

Comment: One could certainly argue that no it isn't! However, it's what my professors have asked for unfortunately...so yes!

Comment: and definitely in python?

Comment: yep, Python 3.2.5

Comment: wasnt aware python could do this, ill have a look for you

Comment: Yes, I've browsed the net (including these forums) thoroughly for an answer and as of yet have only come across some rather complex suggestions such as creating a function that would return to the previous line...it's a shame input can't be followed by  ,end=' '... 
Thank you very much!

Comment: see stans answer as i think that would be better than what mine was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def wordcheck(word):
    if ...:
        return word + " is valid"

    else:
        return word + " is invalid"

print("Proposed word: {0} ".format(wordcheck(input())))
```

Where "if ..." is you checking if the word is valid

Comment: i just tried this, and it works but doesnt give the invalid string on the same line but on the next line which i believe isnt exactly what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

So, Python is a general purpose language, and just as any other language, it has nothing to do with the I/O capabilities - those are up to the ambient you are running it.

he built-in "input" has fixed behavior - and unless you change the terminal behavior for things like "turning  echo off", it will just proceed to the next terminal line when the user press the return key.

Under Windows, the usual way to get more control over the terminal is to use the [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html) library - not you'd have to build your own "input" function based on the several character-reading functions there. Actually if you are on Windows, that is likely the way your teacher wants you to follow.

On any other platform, the high-level way to do it is to use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library.

I hope you can find your way from there.